# Read all CSS selectors using jQuery

Tags: jquery

What is the best way to read all CSS selectors from my CSS `$("head > style:eq(0)").html();` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It varies across browsers. jQuery doesn't help you here, because inspecting the stylesheet data is a quite an unusual thing to want to do, and older/niche browsers can't do it at all. Are you sure you need to inspect stylesheets? What are you aiming to do?

```
var sheet= document.styleSheets[0];
var rules= 'cssRules' in sheet? sheet.cssRules : sheet.rules;
for (var i= 0; i<rules.length; i++) {
    var rule= rules[i];
    var text= 'cssText' in rule? rule.cssText : rule.selectorText+' {'+rule.style.cssText+'}';
    alert(text);
}
```

`cssRules` and `cssText` are standard DOM Level 2 Style properties, `rules` and `selectorText` are for IE<9 compatibility. Note IE<9 will return recreated rules so you'll see eg. `PADDING-BOTTOM: 0pt; PADDING-LEFT: 0pt; PADDING-RIGHT: 0pt; PADDING-TOP: 0pt` if the original style you specified was `padding: 0`.